# Angular Router: loadChildren with parameter

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-router

In my angular router I would like to lazy load distinct modules based on a parameter in the url. Here is a psudo route of my setup:

```
path: ':slug',
loadChildren: async () => {
  
  const SLUG = "How do I get the :slug param from the URL"?;

    switch (SLUG) {
      case 'first':
        return (await import('./pages/first-page/first-page.module')).FirstPageModule;
        break;
      case 'second':
        return (await import('./pages/second-page/second-page.module')).SecondPageModule;
        break;
      default:
        return (await import('./pages/default-page/default-page.module')).DefaultPageModule;
    }
},
```

I tried using resolvers and guards – unfortunately they trigger after the route gets activated, thus I cannot access the parameter beforehand. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Create a single module for `slug` like:
`const routes: Routes = [ { path: 'slug', loadChildren: () => import('./slug/slug.module').then(m => m.SlugModule) } ];`
Then, in `SlugModule`, add route for components like:
`const routes: Routes = [ { path: 'first', component: FirstComponent }, { path: 'second', component: SecondComponent } ];`

Comment: Unfortunately my slug is dynamic, so I cannot map it. For calrification: I use an Angular frontend for a Wordpress backend. I would use the slug (provided by Wordpress) to map it agains a corresponding template using a desingated serverice for that.

Comment: I hope you can map `:slug` to a default component, say `SlugComponent`, and there check for `:slug` from `router` parameters, apply `switch` or whatever there, and navigate to different components or URLs from there.